# Which postulates did Einstein really use in his 1905 derivation of the Lorentz transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, history

Einstein explicitly states in *"Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper"* that the only two postulates he requires for his derivation of the Lorentz transformations are 1) the principle of relativity and 2) the constancy of speed of light (the so-called 2nd postulate).

Many physicists since then, the first being Wladimir Ignatowski 1910 to the best of my knowledge, tried to derive (the form of) the Lorentz transformations without using the 2nd postulate. Instead, most of the derivations I've seen use following postulates or a mix of them:

- homogeneity and isotropy of space (Actually, it is sufficient to only claim isotropy at any point in space. This leads to homogeneity at any point in space.)
- homogeneity of time
- principle of relativity

**My question is:** Does Einstein really only need his two postulates for his derivation? Or did he make some implicit use of some of the other postulates, stated above?

I have a feeling he uses some of these postulates implicitly, but I am having a very hard time figuring out at which exact point in his derivation he uses them.
I did find some [footage](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.4018) which backs my feeling: *Einstein implicitly assumed also that space and time are homogeneous and isotropic, a fact quickly pointed out and stressed by several writers.* (p. 1) But it doesn't tell where and how Einstein uses these postulates.

Doesn't the notion of "speed" in "speed of light" already presuppose homogeneity of time and homogeneity (or isotropy at any point) of space?

If you are kind enough to answer me, please do not use general relativity in your argument. I want to solve this by only using arguments valid within the theory of special relativity.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be a better fit for HSMSE.

Comment: As far as I know, with just the homogeneity, isotropy and relativity principle assumptions, you can narrow down the set of inertial frame transformations to either Galilean or Lorentz. To actually rule out the Galilean transformation, you still need either the constant light speed or the limiting speed assumption. I may be wrong so you can correct me if that's so..

Comment: Dear Shirish Kulhari, you are absolutely right. There is some experimental evidence necessary to determine sign and value of k=c^-2. But unfortunately this does not quite answer my question, which postulates Einstein implicitly might assume in addition to his other two postulates.